# SQLite: Will changing data type affect the database?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I need to change the data type for my SQLite. I am worry that it might effect users who update the App. However, after reading the SQLite document in the following link

https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

It would seem changing the data type when creating a table column shouldn't break the App. From what I read it seems unlike other SQL database engines, SQLite datatype is associated with the value itself and not the column data type that I initially assigned.

I was going to alter the column data type when user updates the App, but it doesn't seem necessary (nor possible without dropping and recreating table). Am I reading this correctly or am I making a mistake?

The App seems to work well when I test updating, but I want to make sure I am not missing anything. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type name in the column definition can affect the [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).
This might change the type of some values (for example, attempting to store the string `'123'` in an INTEGER column will result in the number `123`), and might change how comparisons work (`WHERE SomeColumn = ?` will try to convert the value to the same type as the column's affinity).

So you should change the type name only if you are sure that your app handles the values in this column correctly.